# How to resolve free file fillable forms error S8812-F1040-005?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-credit, free-file-fillable-forms

Seems easy enough to ensure my qualified dependents match (are checked on form 1040) to  what is inputted into line 4a on schedule 8812. Both match but I keep getting a rejected notice.

Issue : Business Rule S8812-F1040-005 - Schedule 8812 (Form 1040), `QlfyChildUnderAgeSSNCnt` must be equal to the number of dependents with `EligibleForChildTaxCreditInd` checked in the return.

The following information may help you determine the form at issue:
Field/Xpath: /efile:Return/efile:ReturnData/efile:IRS1040Schedule8812/efile:QlfyChildUnderAgeSSNCnt

Comment: You can report issues [here](https://www.irs.gov/filing/free-file-fillable-forms/free-file-fillable-forms-support-2) and check for known issues with dates for fix [here](https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/free-file-fillable-forms-help).

Comment: Is the child’s social security number missing or incorrect?

Comment: SS # correct, number of boxes checked on the 1040 match the number inputted in sched 8812.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke to IRS, they know about this issue and said it was fixed internally on Jan.26, they said to either 1.Print and mail return OR..2. Completely delete the return, wait a day and redo entire return and try to resubmit. If then it does not accept, you must print and mail in the return.